# Can I replicate between CouchBase on Android and Couch DB running on Linux?

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase

Can I replicate a CouchBase datbase running on Android to a CouchDB (1.1) server ? I want to try out couchbase on Android and have installed a Couch DB on Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can, but the earlier versions of CouchDB for Android do not support CommonJS.  This may have been fixed by now, I haven't tested it in a few months.

So, if your map/reduce/list/show functions use CommonJS modules, those functions will crash when executed by CouchDB for Android.

If anything does go wrong, check the log file for CouchDB on your Android device.

**UPDATE**

The version of CouchDB for Android was updated yesterday and it should now support CommonJS modules.